# Configure offchain worker with command line argument

Tags: runtime, offchain-worker, cli, oracles

Is configuring an off-chain worker with a command line argument possible?

e.g.

```
./target/release/cere --dev --alice --my-custom-url "http://my-..."
```

If not what are the other options?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to configure it using your own custom node. You can modify the CLI that your custom node uses to expose any flags you need and pipe those values into your OCW when you instantiate it in your `service.rs`.